# find N^(1/17) using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

I faced this simple problem for which I thought there exists a straight forward solution but it doesn't work.

Here's the problem.

Find X s.t X = N^(1/17)

Note:

1. It is ensured that there always exists a integer solution.
2. N denoting a string of length L.
3. 1 <= L <= 34.
4. Sample input: 131072. Corresponding Output:2

Here's a few python code I tried but it didn't clear all test case.

**`Note: All the below mentioned code cleared the given sample input but didn't clear the hidden input.`**

Code 1:

```
number = int(input())

x= pow(number,1/17)

x = int(x)

print(x)
```

Code 2:

```
num = int(input())

x = num**(1/17)

print(x)
```

Code 3:

```
num = int(input())

for i in range(1,110):
    a = pow(i,17)

    if (num-a)==0:
        x = i
        break
print(x)
```

Note: In the third code, the for loop ends at 110, because 110^(17) is of length greater than L i.e. 34 as mentioned in the question.

Also, I tried all possible combination of int and float for input num and (1/17).
 e.g. x =pow(float(num),float(1/17)). Still doesn't work.

I want a python code to explain what cases have I missed so as to not get all the answers.

I don't have access to check the solution now because the portal where the question was posted is closed but even if you post the correct logic I will understand the problem.

Comment: Maybe your third solution doesn't work because you ignore the case N = 0?

Comment: Please specify the version of your python. Becaue "code 2" works in python 3.6!

Comment: N = 0 is not the case. N>0

Comment: Python version is python3

Comment: What input doesn't it work for?

Comment: Please specify if the expected result is always integer. Have you tried any multi-precision package like mp?

Comment: @PresidentJamesMoveonPolk As mentioned in bold in the question, the inputs for which it doesn't work is hidden. I don't know for which input my code doesn't work.

Comment: @LutzLehmann As mentioned in point no. 1 in the note, `it is ensured that there always exists a integer solution.` .Also, we are not allowed to use any packages or libraries or modules so no `mp`.

Comment: So what is the problem with the answer? Just round the result to remove the floating point error introduced by converting the argument to float and taking the root. (a^17+h)^(1/17)=a+h/(17*a^16)+O(h^2/a^33), so the first error term is smaller 0.1 thus not perturbing the rounding result for abs(h)<a^16, making that a very robust procedure. Essentially, you can reconstruct a from the first 3 digits of N under the given assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in python 2.7, you can change a little bit the second code ("code 2") and it will work well:

```
num = int(input())
x = num**(1.0/17) # 1.0 instead of 1
print(int(x + 0.5))
```

However, the second code works well in python 3.6.

Comment: Perhaps (almost certainly) modifying the last line to `print(int(x+0.5))` will solve the "invisible" test case.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Sounds good. I don't know for sure because portal is closed and I cannot check the code but looks correct to me.

Comment: You can just iterate through the list of the 108 cases with input A^17 and compare the output to A. This will also cover the hidden test case.